# Problem Invoking Batch from Button

Tags: visualforce, batch

I am trying to invoke a batch from a button.  I can see in the debug log that the database.executeBatch line is being executed after the button is hit, but it never really invokes a batch job, yet from the Developer Console it works fine.

VF:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="OpportunityUpdateHouseholdController"/>
```

Controller:

```
public OpportunityUpdateHouseholdController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    Opportunity_UpdateHousehold_Batch batch = new Opportunity_UpdateHousehold_Batch();
    database.executeBatch(batch);
}
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Please put the code of vf that you used to call this method to invoke batch?

Comment: It is invoked from the constructor.  I tried it with a method invoked from an action in the VF page, but same result.  If I call the constructor from the Developer Console, it works fine.

Comment: There is no error message, just no batch is invoked.

Comment: Then can we see actual code (here it is invoked in controller and you said it is under button) and debug logs? Because to be honest I see only 2 possibilities - either it is not invoked or it return error.

Comment: The button calls the apex page, which has the one line of code shown above.  The apex page calls the constructor of the controller which has the three lines of code shown above.  So all the code is shown.  The debug log shows database.executebatch line, but in fact no batch is shown in the Apex Jobs.

Comment: Another 2 ideas -  batchable implementation is somehow wrong, or is it possible that scope is null(batch query return nothing/there is some kind error in query string)?
Mayby this code help us. Also why then you need stabdard controller in this page?

Comment: Write a test case for the OpportunityUpdateHouseholdController ensuring that only one batch executes (use less than 200 objects) and wrapping the controller in Test.startTest and Test.stopTest to ensure the batch runs. Include asserts for the results. If that works you know the controller/batch are basically good. After that it must be something to do with the specific execution context.

Comment: Perhaps you cannot start a batch from the constructor of a controller extension. You can't do DML as well, so it could be. Maybe try putting the code in a different function and call that function from the pages `action` attribute.

Comment: Lex, your answer seems to fix the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Apologies @Lex, it appears my answer is very close to your earlier comment. Let me know if your would prefer to answer separately and I'll delete mine.

Comment: If Lex, posts this as an answer, I will credit him with the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

When you call `executeBatch()` an [AsyncApexJob](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/Content/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm?CSHID=sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm) record is created for the batch. It would appear that this is running afoul of the restriction that:

> You can't use data manipulation language (DML) operations in a constructor method in a controller. [Source](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_considerations.htm)

Note that this same documentation explicitly excludes @future methods, which also uses `AsyncApexJob` -

> You can't use the @future annotation in a “getxxx” or “setxxx” method in a controller, or in the constructor for a controller.

It would appear that the same restriction applies to batch jobs, but that it isn't offically documented. What is really odd is that you don't get an Exception for the issue.

As an alternative, see [Calling a dml statement in a constructor of a controller](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10424/calling-a-dml-statement-in-a-constructor-of-a-controller) for a solution using the action attribute on the apex:page do do the DML in a method.

Comment: Nice, it's always a good feeling when a hunch turns out to be correct. I don't mind you getting the rep!

Comment: @Lex It's all good. I made it a community wiki answer so my conscience will let me sleep easy tonight. Salesforce was the winner at the end of the day!

Answer (score 2):

You can not do any Asynchronous call in constructor. Batch is an Asynchronous process.

Instead you can use `action` attribute in  to invoke batch

Ex:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" action="{!runBatch}" extensions="OpportunityUpdateHouseholdController"/>
```

In Apex

```
public void runBatch() {
    Opportunity_UpdateHousehold_Batch batch = new Opportunity_UpdateHousehold_Batch();
    database.executeBatch(batch);
}
```

Instead `<apex:actionFunction>` can be used in same way with javascript.